# Inductive Hypothesis Multiplied By Constant

Tags: proof-writing, induction

When making an inductive hypothesis, does that hypothesis hold if multiplied by some constant?

For instance, could I assume $F_k \geq c \cdot 2^k$ for all natural numbers $k$, and also assume $F_k \geq (2)(c \cdot 2^k)$?

Comment: If all you know is that $F_k\geq c2^k$, then you cannot assume $F_k\geq 2(c2^k) = c2^{k+1}$. That may be false. For example, it is false if you **define** $F_k=c2^k$; then it certainly satisfies the first inequality, but not the second.

Comment: If $F_k \geq c \cdot 2^k$ is an *inductive* hypothesis you do  not assume it "for all natural numbers $k$", only for one *fixed* $k$ used in the induction step. And when you are proving $F_k \geq c \cdot 2^k$ for all natural numbers $k$ by induction your $c$ is a fixed constant that you can not double within the proof.

Comment: @Conifold that makes sense!  thank you very much!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you!